# How to store and display a number of generated thumbnails?

Tags: python, html, image, jinja2

Basically i have some code that generates thumbnails of images and displays it in a .html document.

This is my process at the moment:

1. Read image file
2. Generate thumbnail
3. Store thumbnail in a newly created thumbnail folder called thumbs
4. Display the thumbnail in the page using `<img src='thumbs/thumbnail.jpg>`

The problem is, i seriously doubt the user would like a folder called thumb to be created in every single directory the program uses and have it persist even after the program is closed.

What i need is a way to temporarily store the thumbnails in a way that they can be referenced by the html document. Preferably in RAM if possible.

I'm using jinja2 to generate the html and PIL to generate the thumbnail.

Here is an excerpt if it's needed:

```
def gen_thumb(image):
    if not exists('thumbs'): mkdir('thumbs')
    im = Image.open(image.get('path'))
    im.thumbnail((115,115), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    im.save('thumbs\\'+image.get('name'), 'JPEG')
    return 'thumbs/'+image.get('name')
```

Comment: I only want the memory for the storing of the thumbnails. I'm still wanting to use python to generate the html document for viewing.

Comment: Have you considered just using cloud storage? Take Amazon S3 or Parse (free up to 1m requests) for example. From the amount of details you provided, it seems your problem is you don't want to generate a random folder on your clients's computers to reference an image. I mean, you have to place the image somewhere if you want to use your standard image tag (unless I'm mistaken).

Comment: Uploading a number of images to a cloud server just to display a results page with thumbnails seems a little unneeded.

Comment: Your question still just seems a bit contradictory - if you use ram, how could the image possibly be stored somewhere? It seems like you could just delete the content when you don't need it in some sort of local tmp/ path.

Comment: I guess what i'm asking is pretty impossible. The way i see it is that i have two options, i can store the images in ram and have them served up with a web server in python, or i can use a temporary folder. I was just wondering if there was an easier/better way to go about it.

Comment: If you need temp thumpnails, why not create them on the fly with a handler, which generates the thumbnail when the HTML page gets the thumbnail (s). To cache the new thumbnail, you use the page cache.